Enhancing Dialogflow ES Chat-bot with Data Storage and Display Features
I'm a university student majoring in computer science. Please forgive my limited experience as I'm still in the early years of my studies.
I'm currently working on a final project to develop a chat-bot using Dialogflow ES.
However, I'm looking to add more functionality beyond this.
Firstly, I would like to store user-provided information from the chat as text, so that developers can review this data later.
Secondly, after the chat session concludes, I want to display the stored text information on the next page.
If anyone is knowledgeable about this, I would appreciate their help.
The chat function in the web demo is functioning properly.
I've set up intents and entities to establish the basic framework, and have integrated it into my webpage using integration features with an iframe for web demos.
I've already integrated inline editor powered by Google Cloud Functions for fulfillment.
